# Where is a class method being called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, typedoc

I'm in the process of refactoring a project and have [a method](https://fireflysemantics.github.io/validator/doc/classes/_container_validation_validationcontext_.validationcontext.html#getsignature) that I'm not sure I need.

Is there a way via `Typescript` | `VSCode` | `Typedoc` to see whether the method is being called by any other code in the project?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + F to find in all files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shift + f12 shows where the function is used in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

I always resort to "find & replace" (without replacing) within the project folders. Works almost every time.